# MySQL query for a list where begin date is a day later than another records end date

Tags: mysql

I have an example of the following table. In this example, I want to query for when the program name where bdate is the day after the edate of another.

```
cnum      Program    bdate         edate
1         bob        2012-07-21    2013-08-14       
2         fred       2013-08-15    Null        
3         joe        2012-10-11    Null
4         dan        2012-08-11    2014-12-16
```

I want to find fred using MySQL statement. To help me understand the statement, can the table be called psty.  Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

change table name and * to list of colums you need

```
select * 
    from 
       mytable 
      join 
       mytable t2 
      on datediff(t.bdate,t2.edate)=1
```

[example on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f21507/1)

Comment: why do you think so? I tested it with diff data

Comment: @Strawberry you are absolutly right. Night.. :)  Updated

Comment: Better, but select * is evil. Apart from that, it's a lot like mine, except it can't use an index ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.* FROM my_table x JOIN my_table y ON y.edate + INTERVAL 1 DAY = x.bdate;
```